# Is Shimming Old Framing Okay?

Tags: code-compliance, inspection

I shimmed the framing around a window in a 50 yr old house. Would an inspector find fault with that? Should I remove the shims and leave it in its previous state? I would simply replace the studs, but reaching the sole plate is difficult because the floor is raised a few inches. The sole plate is in effect in a little "pocket". It's hard to get my hands into the bottom of the stud bay and nail even with a palm nailer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't sweat it, you improved the situation. The inspector can see it is old original framing and the header shrunk. It is what happens. It could have been left as it was, but what you did will be fine.

Comment: Yep. If you think about it, those shims are essentially very short studs. No inspector would have an issue with studs carrying a load like that.